# How can I implement a CountedSet (NSCountedSet) in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

Create a generic CountedSet struct that is constrained to Hashable elements. A counted set is an unordered collection of unique elements that may appear more than once in the collection. Use a private dictionary as your backing storage for set members and their counts.

```
struct CountedSet<Element> {
    private(set) var elements: [Element]
    
    mutating func insert(_ element: Element) {
        elements.append(element)
    }
    
    mutating func remove() -> Element? {
        guard elements.isEmpty == false else { return nil}
        return elements.removeFirst()
        
    }
    
    subscript(_ member: Element) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

I don't understand what the real objective is here. The instructions are very confusing at least to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Make your generic struct element conform to `Hashable`, this is necessary because the dictionary keys are required to conform to `Hashable`.

```
struct CountedSet<Element: Hashable>
```

2) The backing storage you have used is an ordered array, not a dictionary and you need to initialize it with an empty one.

```
private(set) var elements: [Element: Int] = [:]
```

3) Your subscript method you need to return the count for the counted set member or zero if it is nil.

```
return elements[member] ?? 0
```

4) Your Insert and Remove methods need to first check the count of a member in the backing dictionary before adding or removing an element from it.

So your CountedSet should look like this:

```
struct CountedSet<Element: Hashable> {
    private(set) var elements: [Element: Int] = [:]
    mutating func insert(_ member: Element) {
        elements[member, default: 0] += 1
    }
    mutating func remove(_ member: Element) -> Element? {
        guard var count = elements[member], count > 0 else { return nil }
        count -= 1
        elements[member] = count == 0 ? nil : count
        return member
    }
    subscript(_ member: Element) -> Int {
        elements[member] ?? 0
    }
}
```

---

```
var countedSet = CountedSet<Int>()
countedSet.insert(3)
countedSet.insert(3)
countedSet.insert(4)
countedSet.elements  // [4: 1, 3: 2]
countedSet.remove(4)
countedSet.elements  // [3: 2]
countedSet.remove(4) // nil
```

Expanding on that you can also make your `CountedSet` conform to [`ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral) to allow you to initialize your `CountedSet` with an array and [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible) to allow you to print its elements:

```
extension CountedSet: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral, CustomStringConvertible {

    typealias ArrayLiteralElement = Element
    init<S: Sequence>(_ sequence: S) where S.Element == Element {
        self.elements = sequence.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }
    }
    init(arrayLiteral elements: Element...)  { self.init(elements) }
    var description: String { .init(describing: elements) }
}
```

---

```
var countedSet: CountedSet = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5]
print(countedSet) // "[5: 3, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 2, 1: 1]\n"
```

Comment: This did help a ton and I was able to complete the assignment. Would you mind explaining the last part of the code. When you used the extensions?

Comment: CustomStringConvertible allows you to provide a description of your CountedSet which returns the description of its elements property

Comment: Thank you, and also the init method as well as the ``` typealias ArrayLiteralElement = Element
    init<S: Sequence>(_ sequence: S) where S.Element == Element {
        self.elements = sequence.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }``` I do not understand the closure with the $0 $1

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral/2908533-arrayliteralelement

Comment: This is a generic initializer. it takes any sequence as long as its element it is the same as the CountedSet element

Comment: { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 } means $0 is the partial result (the dictionary), default provides a value in case the key/value it doesn't exist. $1 it is the current element `+= 1` adds one to the current value

Comment: `func reduce<Result>(into initialResult: Result, _ updateAccumulatingResult: (inout Result, Element) throws -> ()) rethrows -> Result` $0 is the first element of the tuple $1 is the second (inout Result, Element) you could also provide any name you want if you don't you can use this syntax. This is a short version  (the same as)  `self.elements = sequence.reduce(into: [:]) { dictionary, member in  dictionary[member, default: 0] += 1 }`